# AutoMock CreateInstance Type to mock must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class

Tags: debugging, autofac, automocking

I get the generic message below when mocking "autoMocker.CreateInstance<HeliumController>();" with Moq.AutoMock.Automocker. The HeliumController class's constructor take several interfaces. How can I find which specific interface or constructor is failing to mock?

```
{System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Type to mock must be an interface, a delegate, or a non-sealed, non-static class.
   at Moq.Guard.IsMockable(Type type)
   at Moq.Mock`1..ctor(MockBehavior behavior, Object[] args)
   at Moq.Mock`1..ctor(MockBehavior behavior)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Moq.AutoMock.Resolvers.MockResolver.Resolve(MockResolutionContext context)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.Resolve(Type serviceType, Object initialValue)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.Resolve(Type serviceType)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.Get(Type serviceType)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.<CreateArguments>b__58_0(ParameterInfo x)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectArrayIterator`2.ToArray()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.CreateArguments(Type type, BindingFlags bindingFlags)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean enablePrivate)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.CreateInstance[T](Boolean enablePrivate)
   at Moq.AutoMock.AutoMocker.CreateInstance[T]()
   at Helium.Api.Tests.API.v2.HeliumControllerSearchTests..ctor()
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's going to be some trial and error, looking through the types that the constructor takes and then looking to see if any of those don't fit the requirements - I'd first start and look at the sealed classes you're using, since that's probably the cause. Interfaces, non-sealed, non-static, and delegate - those can all be mocked.

I did notice you don't have any line numbers in the exception. I gather things might be getting tested in a "Release" mode so symbols aren't available. Usually exception stacks in "Debug" mode have the actual line number on which the exception occurred - it might help to compile and run the test in "Debug" mode to see the actual line. That could narrow it down.

[Here's where the not-mockable exception is thrown in Moq.](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/f2aa090ff9e161084b6b9c4526d66a7ca03dc167/src/Moq/Guard.cs#L203) It appears they could pretty easily add the actual type name to the exception, it's just not happening. If I were you, [I'd file an issue with the Moq folks](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues) and ask them to update to include the type name in the exception. If they're OK with that, it seems like it might be a pretty easy pull request to submit to them and make the product better, at the same time solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `<InternalsVisibleTo Include="DynamicProxyGenAssembly2" />` can solve this issue.